# NetBeans Remote Development with additional configuration

Tags: c++, netbeans, remote-server

I'm trying to use NetBeans (7.3.1) to work on a remote project.

My configuration is following:

- My local machine is a Windows 7 laptop. It doesn't have any tools. In particular neither compiler nor debugger. But it does have NetBeans IDE and PuTTY for example.
- Source code, Make scripts and (eventually) build results are located on a remote storage shared across servers and "locals". (I might switch to a single server only storage as it is faster but I don't think that it matters at all.)
- I'm accessing it using [SSHFS Manager](http://code.google.com/p/win-sshfs/). SSHFS Manager takes server name, path on the server, user name and SSH private key. In result it mounts that directory on the server as a disk on Windows. This works fine. (Although some directories, possibly links, are represented as files in Windows Explorer, I don't know if that matters...)
- NetBeans project is located on local machine but I don't think that it matters and I could place it remotely as well. But I would prefer to keep it "off source" so that I don't have to add any ignores to version control.
- In NetBeans I did procedure described in [Remote Developement Tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/remotedev-tutorial.html). It seems to be successful. NetBeans connected to the server and found GNU Compiler Collection.
- Then I added the project using File | New Project..., there C/C++ | C/C++ Project with Existing Sources. It seems to be successful. All files are visible and all that staff.

The issue is however that our work "procedure" requires us to setup the environment first. So when I log in with PuTTY for example I have to first call `setsee` with proper argument. And that heavily influences the environment by adding lots of variables for example including:

- `GCC_HOME` which is set to `/opt/gcc/linux64/ix86/gcc_4.3.2-7p3`, as opposed to `/user/bin/g++` which is shown by NetBeans in its GNU Compiler Collection for C++ Compiler and
- `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` which points to some path (while NetBeans doesn't see many includes, probably lacking that path).

So is there a way to tell NetBeans to call `setsee` on the remote server before doing anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that `setsee` is more or less an internal tool. Yet “the core question” remains: how to have an arbitrary script executed on behalf of an SSH session created by IDE, before IDE actually uses that script.

[Answer](https://superuser.com/a/207262/124251) to the “[How can I set environment variables for a remote rsync process?”](https://superuser.com/questions/207200/how-can-i-set-environment-variables-for-a-remote-rsync-process) question on Super User says it all.

To summarize it shortly: in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys one has to modify an entry corresponding to the key with which the IDE will log in. There one has to add a `command` parameter that is a script to be executed after logging in but before “returning control”.

There is also another thing associated with that solution. If the script to be executed within the `command` option outputs anything the it will break many tools (possibly the IDE as well). Such tools often expect on the output whatever the called tool does. Parsing such output fail then on what the `command` script outputs.

A simple solution is to use `tail`. But disadvantage of that is that you loos “progress”. A lengthy operation will look like hung and then output everything in one shot. Also in some cases it simply doesn’t work (for example doing `git clone --progress` through SSH on Tortoise Git will fail if the `command` script outputs anything).